# How do you fix spray paint marks on car hood?

Tags: paint

[image]

I had quite a bit of scratches and a tad bit of dust on my hood and wanted to fix that. I've spray painted cars before but only small areas, nothing as large as the hood. Sanded the affected areas, applied 3 strong coats of primer and gave it around 3 coats of spray paint. Unfortunately, this happened. This image was taken approximately one hour after painting.

This is my second time attempting this. No matter what I do, I always have these marks...what am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to fix this? :(

Comment: Welcome to the site. What equipment are you using (spray gun type, air pressure, etc)? What type of paint are you using (brand, epoxy or ?, etc)? Can you list the steps you took to prepare the vehicle? If you only did exactly what you state in the question, you've left a lot of stuff out of your prep and finishing work to get this right. Did you filter the paint before applying? Did you use the correct amount of hardener to paint (what exactly proportion did you use)? Do you have an air separator on your air lines? Any other information you can provide as to the process?

Comment: I used Dupli Color Perfect Match Reflex Silver paint. I washed and dried the hood, sanded all the faulty material, and then washed and dried again. I primed the hood with multiple layers and then after waiting an hour for the primer to dry, I painted the hood with multiple layers of the Dulpi Color Perfect Match paint, and then waited to try. I made sure to cover the primer and any visible darker parts multiple times. But regardless what I do, it looks like in the image above.

Comment: I'm no paint expert, but I think you're missing a couple of things here. First, did you wet sand the primer with some very fine grit (2000 or even 3000 grit)? Instead of washing/drying, you need to use something like Prep All and a lint free cloth to completely clean the area you're going to work on. You need to have a filter on the air line to prevent moisture from entering. Also, it looks like you aren't getting an even coat and you are arcing the gun as you spray. Gun should be held square to the work. Silver is probably ***THE HARDEST*** color to spray correctly.

Comment: It also looks like you may not have complete coverage.

Comment: Just to clear things up, I'm using can paint and not a gun.

Comment: That could be the major part of your issue right there ... You may want to invest in some real equipment. Even cheaper stuff from Harbor Freight will give you better results than a rattle can. Not only is the silver hard to work with, you are also working on a large area (you know this already) which shows more flaws in your painting. Add to this your choice of equipment and it all adds up.

Comment: After more thorough research, it seems like one of my problems, if not the main problem, is that I was holding the can too far from the hood. It's also why the hood had a rough grainy feel in some parts.

Comment: Also, you are working outside which adds to the difficulty / variables moisture, wind etc. If you can get in a garage that may help but then you have issues of breathing the stuff and overspray.

Comment: One thing - if you mix laquer and enamels, you can get stuff like this. Make sure that your primer and paint are both of the same type.